# installing simstring (SWIG) on python docker image

Tags: python, c++, docker, g++, swig

I'm trying to install the C++ package [simstring](https://github.com/chokkan/simstring) on a python docker image (python:latest or python:3.7)

Steps I take are, following the instructions from the repo / from what I've been able to gather:

```
docker run -it python:latest /bin/bash
autoconf -i
apt-get install swig
git clone https://github.com/chokkan/simstring.git
cd simstring
./configure
cd swig/python
./prepare.sh --swig
python setup build_ext
```

And this is where I get two errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython
```

Somehow I need to pass their locations to build_ext or so I think, but I can't find the file to link, or workout how to link them. Any ideas? (Simstring-pure, the python package is not an option, unfortunately.)

## Update

After building a docker image as per the excellend answer below, I get to the next roadblock,  which looks like iconv is still not found. BTW in 3.7 python this fails to even build. But 3.8 is fine.

```
docker run -it simstring
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 17 2019, 05:36:36)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import simstring
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simstring.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 657, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 556, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1101, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simstring.py", line 17, in <module>
    _simstring = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simstring.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_simstring')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: In case anyone wondered, the speedup compared to simstring-pure is about 20x for lists in the order of 10k entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.16.tar.gz \
    && tar -xvzf libiconv-1.16.tar.gz \
    && cd libiconv-1.16 \
    && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && cd /usr/local/lib \
    && ln -s lib/libiconv.so libiconv.so \
    && ln -s libpython3.8.so.1.0 libpython.so \
    && ln -s lib/libiconv.so.2 libiconv.so.2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y swig vim
RUN git clone https://github.com/chokkan/simstring.git
RUN cd simstring \
    && autoreconf -i \
    && ./configure \
    && cd swig/python \
    && ./prepare.sh --swig \
    && python setup.py build_ext \
    && python setup.py install
```

last result:

```
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simstring.py to simstring.cpython-38.pyc
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simstring-1.1-py3.8.egg-info
```

Comment: This is a great start but I still get the error as per the updated question.

Comment: it makes the image alright. (with CMD python at the end and `docker build -t simstring .`) But using the package fails due to the `libiconv.so.2` not being found.

Comment: see the update , it will work now, please copy the file as it is

Comment: NOTE: this line ` ln -s libpython3.8.so.1.0 libpython.so` is different if you want to use python3.7

Comment: Since `libpython3.8` is being used `FROM python:3.8` is needed otherwise it throws an error.